# Angular 4 Material - mat-button style not being applied in mat-dialog component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I want to create a `mat-dialog` with a default-style `mat-button` for closing the dialog. Everything works except the button lacks the Material Design style applied by Angular Material.

How do I get the style to show? AFAIK I have imported all modules as required and [properly set up each part of Angular Material including the themes](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

`my-dialog.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-dialog',
  templateUrl: './my-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-dialog.component.css']
})
export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

`my-dialog.component.html`:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  ...
</div>
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatCardModule, MatDialogModule, MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyDialogComponent } from './my-dialog/my-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    MyDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You're importing MatButtonModule into the file but it is not listed in the module imports.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Newly imported modules need to be added to `imports`:

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'

@NgModule{
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: MatButtonModule was missing in my case

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, but I don't understand how mat-buttons work in this example I found on their website. They don't import MatButtonModule in their app.module.ts on any of the stack blitzes linked on this page... so how can it work? https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples

Answer (score 38):

Worth noting that the new angular 9 build system requires you stop the "ng serve" script and run it again after adding a material module

Comment: This was my issue. Had everything in right place, just forgot to restart.

Comment: this solved my issue. im actually following a tutorial on youtube and ignored the instruction to stop the server before installing new packages.

Answer (score 13):

can also be missing a line in styles.css

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Comment: this worked for me, strange the ng cli didn't add the stylesheet automatically

Comment: Three years later, Angular 12 still doesn't. This particular gotcha bites me on every new project :-(

Comment: I feel anger and relief at the same time after trying for 2 hours to make the button work... Thanks, this worked for me.

Comment: Honestly baffles me that this isn't plastered everywhere on the documentation...so to add buttons you have to add a package, add it into the module imports, and then add this to your styles.css file...

Comment: I do not see this precisely here in documentation where examples are mentioned ... https://material.angular.io/, thanks , this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

> **TL;DR**
> If you have other things working but not a specific component, **make sure that component's module is imported & imported
> correctly** as modules have to be added to the `imports`:
>
> ```
> @NgModule{
>   imports: [
>     MatCardModule,
>     MatButtonModule
>   ]
> })
> ```
>
> **Note:**
> *Remember to stop the "ng serve" script and run it again after adding the material module as the new angular 9 build system requires to do so.*

**Explanation:**
I had the same issue where I had a *CustomMaterialModule* where I was importing all the **Material Modules** I needed to use in my app. I was using mat-button but its style wasn't there. After a few minutes of searching, I found out that I had put MatButtonModule only in imports array of my *CustomMaterialModule* & not in exports array.

> ***Note:*** my CustomMaterialModule hosts all the Material Modules I need in
> my app so modules like MatButtonModule will go in my
> CustomMaterialModule imports and exports array and later I would only
> use my CustomMaterialModule in other places of my app. I did this to
> keep the code clean and easy for editing. So for example, if one month
> down the road I don't need a Material Module I can just remove it from
> my CustomMaterialModule and not worry about it.

Comment: The reply is pretty old, but what's important to know, is, that you actually have to e.g. import the `MatButtonModule`, too. I am using WebStorm and it showed me, that I had to import `MatToolbarModule` and `MatIconModule`, because it discovered this in the component template. But since I am not using `mat-button` (don't know if it even exists), but `button`, it did not discover, that I also should've imported `MatButtonModule`. After doing so, the appearance was as expected. Tried using Angular 13, SCSS and WebStorm 2021.3.

Answer (score 3):

Some issue that i noticed are -

- import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material' in your my-dialog.component.ts
- constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {} is missing
- MatButtonModule is not imported inside app.module.ts file

You can also follow this(https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) example

Answer (score 2):

Add your dialog in the declarations of **AppModule**. It works for me.

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
...,
**YourDialogComponent**
],

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have 2 extra modules, 1 for the mat-stuff, and another for components.

Initially i added both modules to the app-module but that didnt work.

i moved the mat-module import into the components-module (discarding from app-module, not must) and it worked, i guess its because the DI.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import this package in your app.modoule.ts file

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'
```

and then in imports add this

```
imports: [MatButtonModule,...]
```