# angular material dialog button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I implemented the dialog according to [material documentation example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/omprmymevnj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-elements-example.ts):

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{status}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>{{content}}</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
  </div>
```

[image]

The button however is not working and it doesn't have the style as other elements have.

Does anyone know what might be the cause?

---

this is the content of material.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field'
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';

@NgModule({
    imports: [MatButtonModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule, MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatTabsModule, MatDialogModule, MatGridListModule, MatCardModule, MatSelectModule, MatSortModule],
    exports: [MatButtonModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule, MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatTabsModule, MatDialogModule, MatGridListModule, MatCardModule, MatSelectModule, MatSortModule]
})
```

and this is the app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RecentAnnouncementsComponent,
    CommunityAnalyticsComponent,
    SubscribeComponent,
    UnsubscribeComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Can you show us your .module.ts file? maybe you did forget to import something (MatButtonModule for example)

Comment: Is this your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067153/angular-4-material-mat-button-style-not-being-applied-in-mat-dialog-component

Comment: Yes, this is my case. Don't know why none of the answers from that post works. I have added the description of app.module.ts

Comment: @NikoGamulin is your component a part of any other sub module? if so then you have to add the material module in that sub module

Comment: @radio_head, it is not a part of another submodule. The strange thing is that everything else works as expected.

Comment: @NikoGamulin can you try adding MatDialogModule to your app.module.ts instead of materialModule

Comment: radio_head tried to do it but there is no difference.